# List of properties by ref

Tags: c#, list, properties, ref

I'm trying to generalize a C# class which holds multiple properties of the same type (and all of them have the same implementation as well).

What I want eventually is to remove all properties and hold a single `Dictionary<string, type>` which maps each property using a unique ID.

Removing the properties will be too much of an effort at the moment, but some of the existing functions can be refactored so that instead of multiple 'copy-paste` to read/update a property, use a loop over the future dictionary and update per key.

How can I do the following?

```
//Simplified example
class Person {

    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Age { get; set; }
    public double SomethingElse { get; set; }
    //.. maybe more

    public void CopyPasteCode()
    {
        Height = -1.0;
        Weight = -1.0;
        Age = -1.0;
        SomethingElse = -1.0;
    }

    public void Refactored()
    {
        var properties = //How to do this?
            new List<ref double>() 
            {
                ref Height, ref Weight, ref Age, ref IQ
            };
        foreach(var p in properties)
        {
            p = -1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a bit of an XY problem. Are you really just trying to set all of your `double` properties to `-1`?

Comment: You can achieve it using reflection, for example, e.g. `person.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(person, null);`

Comment: Why would you put those properties in a list? They don't belong together just because their types are all `double`... How would a `loop` help when you still set by `key`?

Comment: The real code is not a `double` rather an element that contains a unique id and a dynamic value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't focus on why you might need such an approach, but rather show a couple of implementation techniques.

#### Option 1: Reflection, string property names

Using this helper method:

```cs
static void SetProperties(object obj, string[] propertyNames, object value)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();

    foreach (var name in propertyNames)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(name);
        property.SetValue(obj, value);        
    }
}
```

you do it like this:

```cs
public void Refactored()
{
    var propertyNames = new[] { 
       nameof(Height), nameof(Weight), nameof(Age), nameof(IQ) 
    };
    SetProperties(this, propertyNames, -0.1m);
}
```

#### Option 2: Reflection, strongly typed, properties specified with lambdas

The helper method:

```cs
static void SetProperties<TObj, TProp>(
    TObj obj, 
    TProp value, 
    params Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>>[] properties)
{
    foreach (var lambda in properties)
    {
        var property = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)lambda.Body).Member;
        property.SetValue(obj, value);        
    }
}
```

and you use it as follows:

```cs
public void Refactored()
{
    SetProperties(
        this, 
        -0.1m,
        x => x.Height, x => x.Weight, x => x.Age, x => x.IQ);
}
```

Using lambdas has the advantage of compiler type- and name-checking, rename refactoring, and picking properties with IntelliSense (when you type `x => x.`).

#### Option 3: Reflection.Emit

Accessing properties through Reflection implies performance penalty, which can be affordable or not, depending on your requirements. A much faster way that provides same performance as the original `CopyPasteCode()`, is using dynamic methods built from IL instructions, which you create on the fly once and then use through the lifetime of the application.

However, if you're new to Reflection.Emit: it's a low-level mechanism, and it requires quite a bit of learning. For this reason, it would be much simpler and faster (and safer) to use one of available wrapper libraries. In this case, Marc Gravell's [fast-member](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) would be a good choice.

Combined with previous options:

```cs
static void SetProperties<TObj, TProp>(
    TObj obj, 
    TProp value, 
    params Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>>[] properties)
{
    var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(obj.GetType()); 

    foreach (var lambda in properties)
    {
        var property = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)lambda.Body).Member;
        accessor[obj, property.Name] = value;      
    }
}
```

the usage isn't changed:

```cs
public void Refactored()
{
    SetProperties(
        this, 
        -0.1m,
        x => x.Height, x => x.Weight, x => x.Age, x => x.IQ);
}
```